# "ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack"

Tags: python, django

I have looked at the questions on here and none of them seem to help my cause. Essentially what I am doing is calling `getAllOpenChoices` to try and return a the value of the Radio button so when one is selected it saves.

**forms.py**

```
def getAllOpenChoices():
    listOpenChoice = [('All', 'All'), ('No One', 'No One'), ('Test','Test')]
    all_choices = Requisition.objects.distinct()
    for choices in all_choices:
           temp = (Requisition.objects.filter(open_to=choices))
           listOpenChoice.append(temp)
    return tuple(listOpenChoice)
```

This error that I am getting is:

```
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

`getAllOpenChoices` is being called:

```
self.fields['open_to'] = forms.ChoiceField( choices = getAllOpenChoices, widget = forms.RadioSelect())
```

Answer (score 0):

The choices should be a list of 2-tuples, like your initial value `listOpenChoice`

```
listOpenChoice = [('All', 'All'), ('No One', 'No One'), ('Test','Test')]`
```

If you extend that list, you should only add 2-tuples. For example:

```
listOpenChoice.append(('new', 'New'))
```

However, you are appending querysets, e.g. `Requisition.objects.filter(open_to=choices)`. This doesn't make sense. One of your querysets is empty, which is why you get the zero in the error message "need more than 0 values to unpack".

It's not clear to me what you're trying to append to the list, so I can't tell you how to fix your code. As long as you only append 2-tuples, you should be ok.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!